# Android Studio: Unregistered VCS root detected

Tags: git, android-studio

Что это значит и почему постоянно возникает?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается двумя способами:

- простое игнорирование этого сообщения, ни к чему плохому не приведёт, но будет действовать на нервы (использовать в случае нежелания интеграции с `GIT`)
- добавление проекта через "add root" и включение интеграции с `GIT` через VCS ·> Enable Version Control Integration